# google cloud compute SSH service to keep running even the computer is turned off

Tags: ssh, google, console

i am doing a really complex task on my google cloud compute and it really takes days to complete even one task. So i don't want to close my SSH terminal. The problem is that here i have electric load shedding problem and i cannot afford to loose what i already have done because it will cost me a lot if i restart the program.
My question is, is there anyway that my work or programs continue even though my PC is turned off. I want the console to run as normal and when the light is gone (i don't know when) it still keeps going and when the light is back i could also look into it that how much is done?

Comment: See if this answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the current workload is gonna to be hosed unless the program can be *ran in the background* while it's still running.

Right now you are running in the *foreground* hence why the SSH session have to be on.

Though there may not be a way to "save it" you could *in the future* avail something like `tmux`. Though like I said since *it's already been running and is* I am not sure if you can attach a `tmux` session to your active session for it to "switch to".

Comment: last time the load shedding occurred, server also stopped working. i know because i saw that in monitor logs it was showing that my CPU is only 0.42% is being used. So it means it was stopped. i don't know how to start a tumux session can you please refer me the method?

Comment: The correct spelling is `tmux` and there are many tutorials on the Internet to get you started.